# Job details in Quartz.NET

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I've asked questions about Quartz.NET a lot today, but I'm making progress in understand and really appreciate you guys helping me. I now think I understand how the jobs work but I have one issue.

For each job, they need to have 3-4 extra fields in the 'QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS', such as pathnames etc. I added these in, but how do I access this information in the jobs so I can use the data in these fields to carry out the job? For example, the job will need to move a file to the specified path, but I'm not sure how to pull the information from that column.

For the columns that are built into Quartz.NET, I know how to access these, which is by doing the following:

```
public virtual void Execute(JobExecutionContext context)
{

    string isvolatile = context.JobDetail.Volatile.ToString();
    System.Console.WriteLine(isvolatile);

}
```

But no methods seem to exist for the new columns I have added. How do I access these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding columns to Quartz tables, take a look at [JobDataMaps](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/tutorial/more-about-jobs.html#jobdatamap). These are persisted in the JOB_DATA column of the QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS table.